# How to format CData text?

Tags: xml, magento2, cdata

I'm trying to format numbers inside Cdata tags like below:

My current code:

```
<ProductPrice><![CDATA[{{ product.price }}]]></ProductPrice>
```

What it shows:

```
<ProductPrice>24.9900</ProductPrice>
```

What I need it to show:

```
<ProductPrice>24.99</ProductPrice>
```

Comment: Are you using Angular JS?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is code from a xml template for product feeds on my magento 2 website so I'm not sure if it uses angular js or not

Comment: Without knowing what technology and code you are using to format the number, there is no way we can tell you what you are doing wrong. If the revelant technology is "magento 2" then use that tag to classify the question, rather than "xml" and "cdata" which are irrelevant.